# Weblogic 12.2.1.3 seems to ignore BindingContextFactory setting

Tags: java-8, jaxb, glassfish, jax-ws, weblogic12c

I currently have two wls in development environment and one .war deployed on both.
One of these wls is in version 12.1.0.3 and some time ago I needed to configure the connection provider because I was having unmarshal problems on some XSD types.
This configuration solved the problems of unmarshal, but I tried to perform the same configuration on another wls that is in version 12.2.1.3 and did not correct the problem.
After this problem, I tried to perform the same configuration in wls version 12.2.1.3 of the ways the oracle site suggests but it seems to have no effect either.
I wonder if anyone else has faced this problem if so I ask you to share the solution found.

```
Configuração realizada em ambos wls: 
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory=com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextFactory


-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContext=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

In the case of wls version 12.2.1.3, I also tried to configure the connection provider configuration at the application level but had no results.

Comment: Any error and stack trace you can post ?